# Spotify Web API, What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, spotify

I'm trying to create a site in which, through the Spotify Web API, I display the information of a certain element (Artist, Track, Album, etc ...).
Not being very experienced in software development, I relied on guides on the Internet and I wrote the following code but it does not give results

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="processRequest()">Try it</button>

    <script>
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Muse&type=track%2Cartist&market=US&limit=10&offset=5", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept: ', 'application/json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type: ', 'application/json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization: ', 'Bearer BQDWk5QhO-CDvXu6nYDbSMP_nubWIMDH6HDX5hPaQlGWIhim4f2qcCJADFVSePyhhCLklKgyXKhPIyRUWa_RpbB97lKKnQHoq4r3ahfw4friE8-fw8gcvchHGDdYv6PuLp1yXDYooNwuNuG-MDhub2WnNj-SUd9W6SadBOhJMeDabIXIWfVMizjeTdldIsNDriPznZnDB4vFTQ4oYfHrSIfh_D9M9noALwOY2cptpC_dKaF7reI-WN1nAEbgGewqTAmtNaOEEuY');
    xhr.send();

    function processRequest(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        alert(response.artists);
        document.getElementById("artists").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
}
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

The only thing that appears is the button, but if I press it, absolutely nothing happens.
I hope you can help me.

Comment: `.setRequestHeader()` expects only the name as the first parameter -> `.setRequestHeader("Accept", ...)`

Comment: What ready state, response code and response message are you receiving?

Comment: after the correction suggested from @Andreas now i've the alert, but it say 'undefined'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. As others point out, the main problem is `'Accept'`.

You can run in the following code in `Full Page`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Index</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
 
    <button type="button" onclick="processRequest()" class="btn btn-primary">Try it</button>
 <div id="artists"></div>
 
    <script>
    /*var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi();
    spotifyApi.setAccessToken('BQDSL01Fr_kd_cph_LVSymXBJu_0gEq75IC3zTSki4eSg_Uwum5tTDUm0d8tvyCQpaXSkfxR32ABFV7sgAZfHUKqMJXLkedeSLDF6v5mU98y3mnlYWZt1wQ_mWhPCTqXCZv-Vt_PWbyxZ-fHQy5Ryp5xby2EBqVTkQ&refresh_token=AQD1ZUVO6xgq7Ol-__h1aE0zf0iqVjsKxzr062CteUsmJZHWA-kT6ebcFpD89D-Qbet99qcbEftR_RrReDvLnWxmK6S4CrjcxFbFXzInLKK-v0JxPNTI6ejC15BBtmlwTAw');*/
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Muse&type=track%2Cartist&market=US&limit=10&offset=5", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer BQDWk5QhO-CDvXu6nYDbSMP_nubWIMDH6HDX5hPaQlGWIhim4f2qcCJADFVSePyhhCLklKgyXKhPIyRUWa_RpbB97lKKnQHoq4r3ahfw4friE8-fw8gcvchHGDdYv6PuLp1yXDYooNwuNuG-MDhub2WnNj-SUd9W6SadBOhJMeDabIXIWfVMizjeTdldIsNDriPznZnDB4vFTQ4oYfHrSIfh_D9M9noALwOY2cptpC_dKaF7reI-WN1nAEbgGewqTAmtNaOEEuY');
    xhr.send();

    function processRequest(e) {
       if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
          var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          var result = '';
          for(var i = 0; i < response.artists.items.length; i++){
             console.log(response.artists.items[i]);    
             result += '<div class="panel panel-primary"><div class="panel-body">' + 
             'name : ' + response.artists.items[i].name + '<br/>' +      
             'popularity : ' + response.artists.items[i].popularity + '<br/>' + 
             'type : ' + response.artists.items[i].type + '</div></div>';
          } 
          document.getElementById("artists").innerHTML = result;
       }
 }
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exactly what your console says: `'Content-Type: ' is not a valid HTTP header field name.`. In order to fix this change these to lines:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type: ', 'application/json');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization: ', 'Bearer BQDWk5QhO-CDvXu6nYDbSMP_nubWIMDH6HDX5hPaQlGWIhim4f2qcCJADFVSePyhhCLklKgyXKhPIyRUWa_RpbB97lKKnQHoq4r3ahfw4friE8-fw8gcvchHGDdYv6PuLp1yXDYooNwuNuG-MDhub2WnNj-SUd9W6SadBOhJMeDabIXIWfVMizjeTdldIsNDriPznZnDB4vFTQ4oYfHrSIfh_D9M9noALwOY2cptpC_dKaF7reI-WN1nAEbgGewqTAmtNaOEEuY');
```

to:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer BQDWk5QhO-CDvXu6nYDbSMP_nubWIMDH6HDX5hPaQlGWIhim4f2qcCJADFVSePyhhCLklKgyXKhPIyRUWa_RpbB97lKKnQHoq4r3ahfw4friE8-fw8gcvchHGDdYv6PuLp1yXDYooNwuNuG-MDhub2WnNj-SUd9W6SadBOhJMeDabIXIWfVMizjeTdldIsNDriPznZnDB4vFTQ4oYfHrSIfh_D9M9noALwOY2cptpC_dKaF7reI-WN1nAEbgGewqTAmtNaOEEuY');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the console for future reference.

Your first mistake is that you shouldn't include the colon `:` in the first parameter.

Secondly, you never set the [`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onload) handler. Without this, the xhr object doesn't know what to do with your retrieved data.

Lastly, using `alert` isn't advised as it won't log the entire response. Use `console.log` and then check the console.

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Muse&type=track%2Cartist&market=US&limit=10&offset=5", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ...');
xhr.send();

xhr.onload = function processRequest(e) {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(response)
    //document.getElementById("artists").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
}
```

Comment: `xhr.onload` is not necessary as he is attaching the `processRequest` function as an event listener.

Comment: True. But I'd be careful about doing that. Imagine the scenario where the response isn't ready but the button was clicked. Nothing would happen and you'd have no way of knowing the response was ready unless you kept clicking the button repeatedly.

Comment: I also don't see an advantage to setting `processRequest` as an event listener for the button and not the xhr object itself since effectively it won't do anything meaningful after the first time it's pressed since the response isn't going to change.